# How did I screw up this very simple .gitignore file?

Tags: git, gitignore

I only want to track one file in my directory.  This file is `buildout.cfg`.  So I first ran `git init`.  Then I created a `.gitignore` file which reads in its entirety as follows:

```
* # Blacklist all files
!buildout.cfg # Whitelist the file I'm interested in
```

But now when I run the command `git add`, git goes ahead and adds dozens of files -- everything in the directory.

Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [`man gitignore`](http://man.cx/gitignore), comments are full lines only. So you should try to move the comments to different lines:

```
# Blacklist all files
*
# Whitelist this file
!buildout.cfg
```